# Adding a new tag in OWL/XML syntax

Tags: java, owl, protege

I have an owl file having owl/xml syntax. I want to add a new tag in this file for making a plugin but when I make changes in the OWL file, parse Exception is thrown in Java.

1st image is the original owl file.
2nd image is the file in which I added a tag but Protege as well as Java cannot parse this file.[image: Original File][image: Edited OWL File]

Comment: Similar question asked by you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297512/how-can-i-make-changes-in-the-owl-file-parsers-so-that-they-would-recognize-new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a new tag means changing the language specification. This requires you to provide a parser that can fit into Protégé - I.e., an OWLAPI OWLParser implementation.

This is a fairly complex task. Your best bet is to check out the owlapi code from GitHub and use its implementation as a blueprint to build your own.

On top of that, your tag will need to fit in the owl 2 model, otherwise your parser will not be able to pass the information to protégé.

What is the purpose of your new tag?

Comment: There is a tutorial for running Protege through Java using maven. What if I make changes in that project?
Will that work?

Comment: Actually I am trying to add new functionality in Protege just for educational purposes.

Comment: Making changes and rebuilding will work, but it's not just the protégé project that needs changing. If you just want to try and modify a parser, I'd do that in the owl api project rather than protégé, as it's an easier first step.

Comment: Okay. I get your point. Can you help me with the api code? Where should I make the required changes?

Comment: If you check out the code, the parsers module is what you need. There's an owlxml parser package in it containing the XML handlers.

Comment: I found the owl api code but I am not able to find the file where I could modify the code. Can you help me with the code?

Comment: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version5/parsers/src/main/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/owlxml/parser/OWLXMLParser.java